# how get checksum or crc

Tags: checksum, crc

i'm trying develop embbeded dev tool to communicate with existing device which have serial communication, which existing software use PC, and i have snif, data like below (REQUEST FROM PC to DEVICE).

**SPLIT DATA by C0**

```
FFFF094D00000096E9EAC0
FFFF094E000000F7AA85C0
FFFF094F000000F7EE8EC0
FFFF0950000000F75250C0
FFFF0951000000F7165BC0
FFFF0952000000F7DA46C0
FFFF0953000000F79E4DC0
FFFF0954000000F7427DC0
FFFF0955000000F70676C0
FFFF0956000000F7CA6BC0
FFFF0957000000F78E60C0
FFFF0958000000F7720AC0
FFFF0959000000F73601C0
FFFF095A000000F7FA1CC0
FFFF095B000000F7BE17C0
FFFF095C000000F76227C0
```

**COMPLETE/ACTUAL DATA**

```
FFFE094DFBE8C0FFFF094D00000096E9EAC0
FFFE094E60DAC0FFFF094E000000F7AA85C0
FFFE094FE9CBC0FFFF094F000000F7EE8EC0
FFFE09509F23C0FFFF0950000000F75250C0
FFFE09511632C0FFFF0951000000F7165BC0
FFFE09528D00C0FFFF0952000000F7DA46C0
FFFE09530411C0FFFF0953000000F79E4DC0
FFFE0954BB65C0FFFF0954000000F7427DC0
FFFE09553274C0FFFF0955000000F70676C0
FFFE0956A946C0FFFF0956000000F7CA6BC0
FFFE09572057C0FFFF0957000000F78E60C0
FFFE0958D7AFC0FFFF0958000000F7720AC0
FFFE09595EBEC0FFFF0959000000F73601C0
FFFE095AC58CC0FFFF095A000000F7FA1CC0
FFFE095B4C9DC0FFFF095B000000F7BE17C0
FFFE095CF3E9C0FFFF095C000000F76227C0
```

**EDITED :**

I have try decode used reveng with command below :

```
reveng -w 16 -i ffff -p 1021 -s FF094D00000096E9EA FF094E000000F7AA85 FF094F000000F7EE8E

width=16  poly=0x1021  init=0xffff  refin=true  refout=true  xorout=0x7e59  check=0x11c8  name=(none)
```

i think from my data FF (front) is header, and last byte (C0) is end flag, 2Byte from last byte is crc ?, but i have try check on online calc http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html & http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html with data FF094D00000096 (first line) and i hope got CRC E9EA, but nothing.

I appreciated if anyone can help me find a crc model or checksum

Regards,

Shidiq.

Comment: Your reveng sequences, e.g. `FE094DFBE8`, are completely different from the examples you give above that, in both length and header bytes.  Is `FE094DFBE8` a complete message?  Are there more header bytes before that? Can you provide a set of those as well (more than three)?  Are there other message length examples you can provide?

Comment: Sorry for that, i just EDITED, with full data, i have cut/split by C0 due i think the data split by C0 and make simple data. the data just have sequece number no length of data (may be)

Answer (score 0):

With the updated, complete messages, there are two solutions to the CRC, where the CRC is applied starting with the lead-in `FFFE` or `FFFF` and up to, but not including the CRC, and not including `C0` delimiter:

```
width=16  poly=0x1021  init=0x0000  refin=true  refout=true  xorout=0xffff check=0xde76  name=(none)
width=16  poly=0x1021  init=0xf01f  refin=true  refout=true  xorout=0x07f0  check=0xde76  name=(none)
```

The resulting CRC is stored in little-endian order after the message.

I'd bet that if you had a set of messages with a third length, the ambiguity would be reduced to the first solution, with a initialization of 0 and a final inversion.

Here is example code in C to calculate the CRC that works on all of your examples:

```
#include <stddef.h>

static unsigned crc16(unsigned char *dat, size_t len)
{
    unsigned crc = 0;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= *dat++;
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8408 : crc >> 1;
    }
    return crc ^ 0xffff;
}
```

I'd wonder if the message is modified if one of the CRC bytes is a `C0`.

Comment: thanks for response, i have adited and add data on my question, ia have change reveng command with add i =init value with ffff and -p = poly value with 1021, i have got Poly, Ini, Xrout, refin & refout true mean litle endian from documentation, but i try track back crc on other site http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html but no result have same

Comment: on your code what mean 0x8408, thats poly ?, if poly why not 1021 ?, sorry i'm new on crc/checksum, and base on java if you have :).

Comment: Java would be pretty much the same, except replace `>>` with `>>>`.

Comment: `8408` is `1021` reflected.  `refin=true  refout=true` means that the CRC is reflected.

Comment: reflected mean little endian ? i have read some article that little endian reverse BYTE order, but if 1021 -> 8408 mean BIT order ? sorry for confusing about little endian, reflected or reverse byte (http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html)

Comment: The _bits_ are reflected. You should be able to see that by inspection. Entirely unrelated to the reflection of the CRC, when the resulting 16-bit CRC is appended to the message, the bytes are in little-endian order, i.e. byte reversed (assuming that you are used to your integers with the most-significant byte first).

Comment: thanks for your explain, i have try code and got the result, i use poly 1021 (not reflected), but the data reflected, and result reflected. that will be same result (theory) if i use 8408 with data not reflected

Comment: Um, ok. Sure. However that is a waste of CPU cycles, reflecting every single byte coming in when you don't have to.

Comment: i try use poly 1021 with data and result reflected bevor last xor we got the same result from this link http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html, but if i use poly 8408 with no data and result reflected the result are diferent on that link, im new on crc, i want use poly 8404 if got the right result :). thanks very much for your response.